# Vue: passing dynamic props to mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to pass dynamic props to Vue mixin from its parent component?
Here are my codes.

This is the `mixin` receiving `isActive` as a prop.

**mixin.ts**

```
export default {
  props: {
    isActive: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    isActive: {
      immediate: true,
      handler() {
        if (this.isActive) {
          // do something
        } else {
          // do something        
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // some methods
  }
}
```

This component calls the mixin above.
I want to pass the `isActiveToBePassed` to the mixin as `isActive` prop.

**component.vue**

```
<template>
 ....
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import mixin from 'mixin';

export default {
  name: "Sample",
  mixins: [mixin], <- ??? how to pass the isActiveToBePassed as a prop
  data() {
    return {
      isActiveToBePassed: false,
    }
  },
  ...
};
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: you don't need to pass anything to mixin. You can directly access `isActive` in your component. `isActive` will be part of your `component` props.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve btw?

Comment: Your right, Naren. I can just use isActive in the mixin not by passing as a prop value. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the right way to use a mixin and/or props. A mixin isn't called, the component simply inherits its properties/methods.

Props are designed to be passed from parent to child components. A component cannot pass props to itself.

If you want to modify a component's own property you are probably better off using `data` rather than `props` in the mixin.

Otherwise update the property in the component's parent which will then cause your child including mixin props to update.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Storey.
> Props are designed to be passed from parent to child components. A component cannot pass props to itself.
I see. Yeah, it makes sense. So I need  a workaround instead:)